# NSMutableAttributedString adding multiple attributes hiding the text

Tags: ios, swift

```
let text = "By accepting  you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy."
let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

attr.setAttributes([.underlineStyle: 1, .foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7294117647, green: 0.6235294118, blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1).cgColor ],
                   range: (text as NSString).range(of: "Terms of Service"))

attr.setAttributes([.underlineStyle: 1, .foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7294117647, green: 0.6235294118, blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1).cgColor ],
                   range: (text as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy."))
```

> This is the showing in terminal
>
> -[__NSCFType set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000039b2ca0

When adding single attribute it is working fine

Running Code on **iOS Simulator 13.2.2**, **Xcode 11.2.1**, **Swift 5**

Comment: Remove `.cgColor` (twice). It should expect a `UIColor`, not a `CGColor`.
From the doc: "The value of this attribute is a UIColor object. Use this attribute to specify the color of the text during rendering. If you do not specify this attribute, the text is rendered in black."  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1533563-foregroundcolor

Answer (score 0):

Here is it you need to convert the cgColor to UIColor to use foregroundColor attribute

```
attr.setAttributes([.underlineStyle: 1, .foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.556, blue: 0.232, alpha: 1)],
                      range: (text as NSString).range(of: "Terms of Service"))



 attr.setAttributes([.underlineStyle: 1, .foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.556, blue: 0.232, alpha: 1) ],
                          range: (text as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy."))
```

Comment: Why? Why `UIColor(cgColor: someUIColor.cgColor)`? Why not directly `someUIColor`? Because you are doing `UIColor => CGColor => UIColor`.

Comment: @Larme ,Thank you for your insight have edited the answer to reflect that change